# Slide thru on wordpress lightbox for images

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ipad, lightbox

I have not been able to figure out how this can be done.

Im currently using this plugin called jQuery Lightbox . On Ipad I need to be able to slide

through the images rather than clicking the previous,next button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are quite a few of these, but here's a lightbox jQuery plugin that supports swiping through images:  [TouchTouch](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/04/mobile-touch-gallery/)